# Binary Division using logic gates

Tags: computer-architecture, arithmetic, digital-circuits

I am building a 64 bit CPU in Minecraft and I'm stuck on adding division into the ALU. I was told I should ask this here. Does anyone know how to divide in binary using only logic circuits? I can't use any counters or registers, just logic gates.

Comment: See if [this thesis](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:347845/FULLTEXT01.pdf) helps.

Comment: You are in the right place, but your question is quite broad. Assuming you have already implemented other parts of the ALU, you have some knowledge of how circuits work. What, specifically, do you get stuck with building a divider? Which resources have you checked? I would guess that there are plenty of open ALU designs for you to find.

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements? It sort of looks like you intend to build a non-iterative divider, it will be pretty big.